# solrj error: array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, solr, jetty, solrj

hi im trying to run this code and i can seem to figure out what is wrong..sorry im new to solrj

```
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField;


public class SolrjTest
{
    public void query(String q)
    {
        //CommonsHttpSolrServer server = null;
        SolrServer server = null;

        try
        {
            server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/");
            //server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/");
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("not connected");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery(q);
        query.setQueryType("camera");
        query.setFacet(true);
        query.addFacetField("name");
        query.addFacetField("locality4");
        query.setFacetMinCount(2);
        query.setIncludeScore(true);

        try
        {
            QueryResponse qr = server.query(query);

            SolrDocumentList sdl = qr.getResults();

            System.out.println("Found: " + sdl.getNumFound());
            System.out.println("Start: " + sdl.getStart());
            System.out.println("Max Score: " + sdl.getMaxScore());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> hitsOnPage = new   ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

             for(SolrDocument d : sdl)
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> i = d.iterator(); i.hasNext();        )
                {
                    Map.Entry<String, Object> e2 = i.next();

                    values.put(e2.getKey(), e2.getValue());
                }

                 hitsOnPage.add(values);
                System.out.println(values.get("displayname") + " (" +  values.get("displayphone") + ")");
            }

            List<FacetField> facets = qr.getFacetFields();

            for(FacetField facet : facets)
            {
                List<FacetField.Count> facetEntries = facet.getValues();

                for(FacetField.Count fcount : facetEntries)
                {
                    System.out.println(fcount.getName() + ": " + fcount.getCount());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SolrServerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SolrjTest solrj = new SolrjTest();
        solrj.query(args[0]);

    }
}
```

im having this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at SolrjTest.main(SolrjTest.java:98)
```

and it is pointing in:

```
solrj.query(args[0]);
```

i also have an additional question cause before im having this output whenever i run a sample program in solrj

```
{time=218.0,sub1={time=125.0,sub1.1={time=31.0}}}
```

can you tell me what this means and the error about array out of bounds? thanks in advance really need this badly and dont know much about solrj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are not supplying any runtime parameters while program execution starts.

In `solrj.query(args[0]);` , `args` refers to the parameters passed to the program like:

```
java MyClass abc def
```

So here in the above case `args` will be :

```
args[0]   ----->   "abc"
args[1]   ----->   "def"
```

So make sure you are passing proper parameters while executing your program.

Comment: does this mean that i could replace args[0] to "abc" or any string?

Comment: yes you can, but keep in mind that whatever you set it will passed to your `query` method.

Comment: hi my program now runs, i also added commons-logging jar file and followed your advise thank you so much!!